# MMC snap in windows form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, webforms

I want to show MMC snap in my windows form application.

I have added a panel in windows form. Now I want to show IIS (MMC) in this panel.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start it as process and set parent to your window.

```
Process p = Process.Start("mmc");
p.WaitForInputIdle();
SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project) is an example.